# Invoking the default constructor (in Java) in a class that only has a defined constructor that requires parameters

Tags: java, default-constructor

Please tell me if I have the proper understanding of the following code:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    a.print();
  }
}

class A {
  String s;

  A(String s) {
    this.s = s;
  }

  void print() {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

The line “A a = new A();” invokes the class/constructor to create a new object with reference variable “a”. Class A has a defined constructor that requires a string argument, thus it does not have the default constructor. This means that the instantiation without any string arguments causes a compiler error.

If I were to add a string argument into the instantiation, e.g. A a = new A("goldfish");    the program would compile and run.

I am not sure if I have used the right vocabulary for this, so feel free to correct anything that is inaccurate/confusing. Thanks!

Comment: A default constructor is only created in a class with no constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is pretty much correct. The one thing that I would change is "create a new object" to "create a new instance of A" with a reference to a java.lang.String in parameter `s`. In this case the constructor assigns that parameter to a field, but it can do something else with it entirely (such as use it to calculate a different value for some field).

Comment: Creating a new object of type `a` is the same as saying Creating a new instance of `a` AFAIK, although in Java (where they almost always refer to class instances as objects) I'd prefer the the former. Another thing, what exactly do you mean by *'reference value a as a parameter'*

Comment: @AndrewL. Fixed the latter terminology; it was poorly worded.

Comment: `a` isn't a parameter, it's a reference to an object in memory.

Comment: @AndrewL. Meant to say `s`. I should probably re-check more carefully next time.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is roughly correct.

To be more precise: "invokes the class/constructor" is not entirely correct. `A a = new A();` *intends* to invoke the *constructor* (invoking a class doesn't mean anything).

Though constructors are not methods, you can think of them a bit like methods: if your class has defined a method like so :

```
public void myMethod(String s) { ... }
```

Then trying to call `myMethod()` without any argument would fail. It's the same here.